# Cannot upload file via curl and PHP

Tags: php, curl

I try to upload a file to server via curl and PHP.

The curl command is:

```
curl -d userfile=C:\myfile.dat 
--data-binary @C:\myfile.dat 
-H 'multipart/form-data' 
http://127.0.0.2/upload-file.php
```

and the upload-file.php is:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'C:/wamp64/www/blogs/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

But the upload always fail. The PHP code is copied from the sample in https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php